# LoadError Unable to autoload constant Message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemodel, rails-models, mailboxer

In my app; when I submit form, I get this error:

```
LoadError at /questions
Unable to autoload constant Message, expected /app/models/message.rb to define it
```

It points to the `create` action in the `Questions` controller:

```
@message = current_user.messages.new(:subject => "You have a question from #{@question.sender_id}"`
```

Message model:

```
class Mailboxer::Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :notification_id, :receiver_id, :conversation_id
end
```

Comment: It looks like a namespace issue. How is the relationship between user and messages defined, and where is the `Message` model defined?

Comment: @Sharagoz If I remove the `Mailboxer::` from the name I get the error `Table 'dating_development.messages' doesn't exist`. Which makes sense since there is no messages table, only a notifications table. I just realized `Mailboxer::Message` should go into a subdirectory, but I'm going on the wrong path if I start going down that road.

Comment: Can you share the `User` model in the question.

Comment: @pwz2000, please share ` Question Model `

Comment: @KirtiThorat user model added

Comment: @Acacia Question model added

Comment: @pwz2000 You're trying to treat the `Message` class as an `ActiveRecord` model. If the message class does not map to a database table then you cannot refer to it from the `User` model as an association. That's why you're getting the errors you see.

Comment: For starters, I just notice I'm not suppose to have a Message model with Mailboxer. So that has been removed. In the controller I did add the line under the create action `@conversation = Conversation.create!` to see what kind of error I will get. It gives me a `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid` that says `Validation failed: Subject can't be blank`. So my thought is it has something to do with the Question model.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

By convention in rails (and this is enforced by autoloader), file paths should match namespaces.

So, if you have a `Mailboxer::Message` model, it should be in `app/models/mailboxer/message.rb`.

Additionally, you probably have autoloader kicking in when trying to load a `Message` class (my guess is that it happens from within ActAsMessageable). It looks for a `message.rb` file in the load path, finds it in `app/model/` and thus loads that file so it can find the `Message` class.

Problem is, it doesn't find a `Message` class in that file, only a `Mailboxer::Message` class (which is different). This is why it throws "Unable to autoload constant Message, expected /app/models/message.rb to define it".

To fix that, create directory `app/models/mailboxer/` and put `Mailboxer::Message` in it.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I removed the message model as it was not needed to begin with, but your point is 100% correct.

Comment: YESSSSSSSS! My week long search is over. This is so uncomfortably correct!

Comment: I had a case mismatch in the class name: I was referencing `API::` instead of `Api::`

Answer (score 3):

I got this during integration testing. Turns out, it was fixtures related. Had to delete the my unused file in /test/fixtures/wrong_name.yml

Comment: Same thing here... I could have spent hours to find the culprit. Thanks a lot. This is an example of magic turning into insanity...

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the documentation, to send a message from `A` model to `B` model you have to add:

```
acts_as_messageable
```

in both models.

And then do:

```
a.send_message(b, "Body", "subject")
```

So in your models:

```
  class User < ...
    act_as_messageable
  end
```

`@question_sender` must be a `User` instance.

```
@question_sender.send_message({attr_accessor_hash}, recipient_user, @question.body, "You have a question from #{@question_sender.id}")
```

As long as the `attr_accessor` is not related to the gem, and the method send_message is not aware of this attributes you will have to redefine it:

https://github.com/mailboxer/mailboxer/blob/master/lib/mailboxer/models/messageable.rb#L60

add the attr_accessor_hash to method

```
def send_message({attr_accesor_hash}, recipients, msg_body, subject, sanitize_text=true, attachment=nil, message_timestamp = Time.now)
```

And look at the code add the fields where you need as: `attr_accessor["param"]`

Comment: It points to ``undefined method `attr_accessible' for Message:Class``

Comment: I am unable to use accessor without ActiveRecord as it gives the error ``undefined method `arel_table’`` which points to the line `@message = current_user.messages.new`. Adding AR back to the model will give me ``Table 'dating_development.messages' doesn't exist`` which also points to the same line.

Comment: Are you using any gem? This datin_development table is not pasted anywhere but in the error.

Comment: Yes, I am using the mailboxer gem. The Questions controller is on it's own, I am trying to make it connect to the Mailboxer so when a User fills out the Question form it will then create a message to recipient with the details of the message inside (body of the message will be the Question).

Comment: Then the question should contain that info. I wasn't aware of that gem :| Let me check the info!

Comment: My apologizes! Any help would be appreciated :) I will keep digging into it myself of course

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56036/discussion-between-jorge-de-los-santos-and-pwz2000).

Answer (score 0):

Notice these lines;

```
@question = Question.new(params[:question])

@question.message = @message
```

and ;

```
attr_accessible :answer, :question, :sender_id, :recipient_id, :conversation_id
```

The `@question.message` line is calling an attribute that is not accessible in the `Question Model` so do this;

```
attr_accessible :answer, :question, :sender_id, :recipient_id, :conversation_id, message
```

Comment: I tried that before. It points to the same error unfortunately. I think it has something to do with the Message model I had to create.